# Google Maps Api to find business name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm making a website for Italy service taxi, I want to replicate the autocomplete place search as in another website.

The other website uses Web Service API, I use Javascript API, but the Google Map library I think is the same....

For example if I write in other website: 'hotel president milano', it suggests me "NH Collection Milano President, Largo Augusto, 10, 20122 Milano, Italia", exactly what I want to know!

If I put in my website 'hotel president milano' I receive no suggestion! It only shows me the suggestion when I write "nh collection milano", if I change words position "collection nh milano" or "milano nh collection" I receive nothing.

Comment: its seems like they have customized the results....

Comment: this is another one https://www.meetingrooms.com/

Comment: @NifalNizar: the results as they are come from google

Comment: @Cristian: as it seems they have a premium license, maybe you get different results with different licenses

Comment: Maybe could be the license https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely to the requests that are being made they are using another service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

So the results you're basicly comparing oranges and apples here. Plus some of your search queries worked fine for me.

Comment: They don't use javascript but web service Api.. Queries in general works fine, but some business names search as 'hotel president milano' are not found... I would to know what is the difference using the same Google Place Library....